# React Native - catch all touch events but Touchable's are not bubbling

Tags: javascript, react-native, touch

I've made a tooltip and I want it to close on a touch event outside the tooltip. However I don't want to make an opaque view because I still want the touch to work on whatever was pressed.

I tried wrapping my app in a `TouchableWithoutFeedback`:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(e) => this.onAppTouch(e)}>
```

This works if the element pressed isn't a `Touchable`, but otherwise the event seems to get swallowed and not bubble up to that top level `onPress`.

Is there a way to get this to work or else an alternative? Thanks.

Edit: this seems to be a limitation of Touchables (they swallow up gestures) - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6796

Answer (score 0):

If you render your tooltip components after a touchable background component with TouchableHighlight you will preserve the touchable tooltip characteristic because of the rendering order of you components.

So you will have:

|Tooltip1| |Tooltip2|
|Background Touchable|

If you want to hide it or shown it depending on your state:

```
var touchOn = (<TouchableHighlight>Background Component</TouchableHighlight>)
var touchOff = <Your other component/>
```

And the to control the state and render one or the other write the condition:

```
{this.state.openTooltip ? touchOn : touchOff}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with that is I still want the app to react to the touch - e.g. if the tooltip is open and something else touchable is pressed, the tooltip should close and the action should still happen on whatever was touched. A Touchable background will block that right?

Comment: Hmm so If you touch on a tooltip and it opens you can change the state and then render a touchable background and once you click on that background you change the state and change the render to not shown that background

Comment: Yep but if you press on the background and there is a button under it, the background will block the button press right?

Comment: Yes, so if you want the button to be available on press just render the background before the button.

Comment: The problem is I still want to close the tooltip if that button is pressed ;) Catch-22

Comment: So on the onpress function you have on the button manage if there is a tooltip already opened

Comment: I know it's long gone since you asked this question. Putting this link here for future devs asking the same question as you. [How to detect click outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478348/1903781). The approach uses internal React private props due to lack of alternatives.